# get particular element via jsoup

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

i want to select td.team in such way for 1st textview1 i want td.team (1st td.team ) and for 2nd textview i want (2nd td.team ) ...  i am using list apdater

Elements info = dpc.select("td.team "); but it giving me both team it 1st and 2nd so how i can do it .. pl tell me what Elements shld u use to get info

```
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="date">10</td>        
    <td class="team"><a href="abc" title="M">one</a></td>
    <td class="team"><a href="abc/" title="d">two</a></td>
    <td class="type">8M</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="date">01</td>  
    <td class="team"><a href="asd" title="Nice">Nice</a></td>
    <td class="team"><a href="asd" title="Monaco">Monaco</a></td>
    <td class="type">€ 4.1M</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td class="date">07</td>
    <td class="team"><a href="sad" title="Monza">thre</a></td>
    <td class="team"><a href="asd" title="Nice">fou</a></td>
    <td class="type"> 600K</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td class="date">99</td>        
    <td class="team"><a href="sad" title="Marsala">M/a></td>
    <td class="team"><a href="asd" title="Monza">a</a></td>
    <td class="type">50K</td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i really don't understand your question. Do u want to get the first td from each row and second td from each row. If thats is the case you need to form an array.

```
Elements info  = dpc.select("tr.odd,tr.even").select("td.team");

    int i = 0;
     String linkText = "";
     String cse_id = null ;
     ArrayList<String> s =new ArrayList<String>();


    for(Element el : info ){
        linkText = el.attr("href");//or el.attr("title")
        s.add(linkText);
     System.out.println(linkText);/or print it



        }
    }
```

There might be some errors in the code i didn't test it .

Answer (score 0):

'Select' method returns a 'Elements' object. This class has a method called 'get(int index)' which returns the i-th element in the selection, starting from zero.